# How to echo an "*" character to console in shell

Tags: linux, sh

I'm trying to test a disk erase utility I've written with dd by looking at the following output:

```
00000000
*
00000200
```

I current wrote a short sample loop in shell script to iterate through the output and print it out just to verify the output:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=sample bs=4M count=1
results=`dd if=sample bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C | awk '{ print $1 } '`
for i in $results
do
   echo -e "$i"
done
```

but it prints out the directory listing when it hits the "`*`" character. If I try to escape it, then it'll just print out "`$i`". Using the following if-else construct didn't seem to help:

```
if [ "$i" == "\*" ] #using "*" didn't seem to work either
then
    echo -e "\*"
else
    echo -e "$i"
fi
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: or just use a different char? `#` ? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, seeing as i'm using awk anyways, I don't know why I didn't think to just use gsub to replace it... If you post that as an answer I will accept, since the char doesn't have to be `*`, it's just what dd provides

Comment: Good question.  I'm trying to figure out how to display echo statements from my build script to the console during the build.  I cannot find it in Xcode6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, "thinking outside the box",

just use a different char? `#` ?

IHTH

Comment: +1 to all the others that did the heavy lifting on answering the question as posed. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the asterisk is expanded in the `for` already. To avoid that, use `read` instead of the backticks and array instead of a string:

```
results=()
while read line ; do
    results+=("$line")
done < <( dd if=sample bs=512 count=1 | hexdump -C | awk '{ print $1 } ' )
for i in "${results[@]}" ; do
    echo -e "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have exact content, quote with single quote

```
$ echo '*'
```

A bit of reading about quoting in bash here : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quoting.html

Comment: Does not work. The problem is getting to that line, if my if-else could get to `"\*"` that would work as well. But it doesn't. There is no way to use `'$i'` as that would just print `$i`.

Comment: maybe you could try to disable pathname globbing `$ set -f` and reenabling later with `$ set +f`

Answer (score 1):

No need of creating `$results` variable and then listing it in for loop.

You can list your output using awk itself:

```
dd if=sample bs=512 count=1 2>/dev/null | hexdump -C | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Comment: Right now I'm just listing to see how I would manipulate it in a script, I'm well aware that above line will output it to the console. I'm trying to learn how to use a for loop to iterate through this type of problem.